# Java - Creating multiple objects and making them distinguishable

Tags: java, object

My program reads from a text file to create objects depending on which pattern it matches. It's one at least but it could be up to 4, depending on the file,  and I need each of them to be stored individually. If `object1` does not exist, create it, if there already is an `object1`, create `object2`. But I'm struggling with either the IDE telling me that I have not yet instantiated `object1` or it ends up just creating `object1` all the time (when I move it to the class variable). I can understand why it would do that, but I'm at a loss when it comes to how to solve it.

So I tried something like this:

```
MyObject object1;

if(patternMatchFound){
     if(object1 == null){
         object1 = new MyObject();
     }else if(object 1 != null){
         object2 = new MyObject();
     }else if(object2 != null){
         object3 = new MyObject();
     }else if(object3 != null){
         object4 = new MyObject();
     }
  }
```

This always creates the first object only (since `object1` is always null I guess). But how can I work around this? How to check whether an object already exists and create a new one if required?

Comment: `But I'm struggling with either the IDE telling me that I have not yet instantiated object1` This statement from you makes me think that you lack too much basics. Answering your question will  basically mean giving you a lecture on several chapters worth of knowledge in Java. Your question is also unclear. How is your object represented in the text file. What are the properties of MyObject?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. In this code object1 is always null an so if the condition

```
patternMatchFound
```

is true then the first if is executed.

I dont know your real problem but out of the info you provide you have to execute your if-statements 4 times

```
MyObject object1,object2,object3,object4;

for(int i = 0; i<4 && patternMatchFound; i++){
 if(object1 == null){
     object1 = new MyObject();
 }else if(object 1 != null){
     object2 = new MyObject();
 }else if(object2 != null){
     object3 = new MyObject();
 }else if(object3 != null){
     object4 = new MyObject();
 }
}
```